# Procedure to convert continuous equations of motion to discrete version

Tags: simulation, numerical-modelling, discretization

Let's take a mobile robot and suppose we know its continuous equations of motion, for example [this](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node658.html) car-like simple model.

Now if I am simulating this robot in a continuous 2D plane, then coding the simulation is simple. But suppose i am now in a 2D grid world. Movement is only from one cell to another cell. Now how do i simulate this motion given that i only know its continuous version.

I remember seeing purely discrete equations like those for a cellular automata are derived once and for all, and then these purely discrete equations are naturally used in the grid world just like continuous equations are used naturally for the continuous world.

Is there a good example that teaches how we can go from ODEs to CA-like equations?